# Opposite of Envy

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word that describes the opposite of envy in this situation. Example: If a mother sees another mom with a child who is well-behaved and makes good grades that mother might be envious, wishing she had a child like that. The word I'm looking for should describe the opposite of that in this example:  A mother sees another mother with a child who has Autism or is handicapped and that mother is glad that she doesn't have a child like that. Someone has already suggested the word content but that doesn't really work here.

Comment: What makes you feel that you've exemplified an opposite of _envy_? Both situations in your examples seem to me to stem from meanness, thereby being similar and not opposite.

Comment: The opposite of `envy` would be `pity` but that's not exactly what you're asking about

Comment: @anemone I can see what you are saying. I think that clawson probably intends to express something more like "Seeing the poor child of that mother helps me be grateful that my child is well" instead of "I am grateful that my child is better than hers".

Comment: I consider it my duty to remind to OP of the need for research. Where have you looked? What have you found? ...

Comment: @anemone: OP presumably means "from the opposite perspective" (like the difference between "lend" and "borrow"), not opposite in perceived worthiness.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms Yeah, that's possible. Still, I perceive two rather different questions here. One -- what the opposite of envy is (assuming that for some reason _envy_ does have an opposite). Two -- what's the name of the feeling some people have upon seeing a mother with an autistic child &c. and being glad they haven't got a child like that.

Comment: Please [edit this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/231638/edit) so that it appears more specific and can be reopened. I think the title might be hindering you here (see comments from others above).

Comment: As the question stands, it's ambiguous and at least partly OT. No answer can be an "answer" to such a question. The OP can start with https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=envy+antonym and research.

Answer (score 11):

There are many words to describe this. Here are a few:

- Relieved
- Thankful
- Grateful
- Lucky

Comment: ... or the *glad* the OP himself used without even noticing.

Answer (score 9):

> I proffer - **[contentedness](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/contentedness)**
>
> - the state of being **contented with your situation** in life. (vocabulary.com)

Also, what about "[goodwill](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/goodwill)".

- a kindly feeling of **approval and support** :  benevolent interest or concern. (MW)

Comment: I agree, if I am envious, I want things I don't have. If I am contented, I do not want things. this works very well.

Comment: Yeah, they're opposites. If you're content you can't be envious

Comment: This doesn’t fit the situation. The absence of want isn’t the polar opposite of want. The opposite of desire is repulsion. Mutual exclusivity is not a good test for opposites.

Comment: -1 because "contentedness" does not address how the emotion was inspired by observing another person (whereas "envy" clearly does -- so its opposite must, too)

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung, great point, Mutual exclusivity is not a good test for opposites. ++

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Sam's how about:

She will feel [fortunate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fortunate?s=t)/[blessed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blessed?s=t)/[advantaged](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/advantaged)/lucky.

Comment: It describes the emotion in the example, but this is not actually the opposite of envy.

Comment: @ jprete True  fortunate/blessed/advantaged/lucky are not actually the opposite of envy.They however fit the situation the good OP describes.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe sounds like **[schadenfreude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude)**: “pleasure derived from the misfortunes of others”

The mother in your example doesn’t pity the other mother, she doesn’t empathize, and she’s not content. She gets a pleasure (possibly guilty) out of the fact that someone has it worse than she.

I don’t think most people would consider this the opposite of envy, but I think envy has too many component parts to have a perfect opposite.

Though this is a single-word request, comments from OP have led me to think that combining this word with another suggestion might be best. I present: **“smug schadenfreude”** *[(examples)](https://www.google.com/search?q="smug+schadenfreude").*

Comment: schadenfreude doesn't really fit with the examples, as it describes the feeling of joy **because** of the misfortune of others, not feelings of joy because oneself **doesn't have** those "misfortune" (although in some cases this might be a fine distinction).

Comment: -1 same reason as tim

Comment: @tim Nobody experiences schadenfreude for people in the same boat, as far as I understand it. Perhaps this is the fine distinction you mention, but is there a better word? OP already said “contented” is not it and most other suggestions seem to be in that same vein.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung I would say that you actually can feel schadenfreude even if you experience the same thing (eg you just fell down the stairs, and see your friend falling down right after you, you could be feeling schadenfreude). But my main point was the motivation: with schadenfreude, the joy is created directly out of the misfortune of others, while the examples of the OP seem more along the lines of getting joy out of ones own situation, aided by seeing others in a different situation. But no, I don't really have a better word for that either.

Comment: Think I'm leaning more toward schadenfreude, smug or complacent. These are good words to describe when someone is disdainfully proud due to someone else's situation. I was looking for something of a haughty nature...snobbishly felt. Thanks.

Comment: @clawson It’s a big relief to hear that I picked up on the tone in your question. Out of those three, I like “smug” as accessible and economical, though “smug schadenfreude” splits the difference in a really nice way.

Answer (score 2):

I admit this is far removed from the example in your question but in polyamourous communities they refer to the opposite of envy/jealousy as:

> **Compersion:**
>   1)The feeling of joy one has experiencing another's joy,
>   such as in witnessing a toddler's joy and feeling joy in response.
>   2)The feeling of joy associated with seeing a loved one love another;
>   contrasted with jealousy.

(src: Wikipedia)

In my experience it tends to be used more in the second sexual context so maybe not useful to you.

Comment: +1 terrific answer. I would point out that number 2 contrasts with jealousy, while we are trying to contrast with envy -- and jealousy and envy are slightly different (though whoever wrote #2 might have actually meant to say "contrasted with jealousy or envy")

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to say that a person is in a situation that another would not envy, the word that best suits the situation would be [unenviable](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/unenviable), though you would have to use it in a different way.

> **Unenviable**
>
> adjective
>
> d: very bad or unpleasant
>
> > *I was given the unenviable task of cleaning the toilets.*
> >
> > *He found himself in the unenviable position of having to admit he'd lied*
>
> [Mirriam-Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/unenviable)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off with something like **unselfishness**, **selflessness**, or even **altruism**.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how strong the emotion is "proud" can be the opposite of envy. Though in your example"satisfied" || "fulfilled" || "contented" seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The word that seems most appropriate to your example is 
**[smug](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/smug)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish another person's ____ was yours, you feel **envy**.

If you're glad another person's ____ is not yours, you feel **pity**.